# How do I extract data from a response to a callback URL?

Tags: reactjs, api, express, routes, react-router

I need to integrate payment for a booking service I currently develop.

I use React.js as front end and NodeJS/Express for back end.

I have set up a route on my express server, /payment, and in the /payment route I basiclly take an data object with some costumer data and then I send along the data with a axios POST request to a /apiURL, I then get a response and send another POST request to /apiURL/responseID and then get I recommended by the API company to set up a callback URL(that should be a data parameter in the first call) to which the API will send a postback request when the costumer has fulfilled the payment.

So my question is, how do I extract this callback response data? Can I somehow await it and extract in the same route?

Since I use React should I make components that respond to there callback URLs with React Router?

Or do I have to make like a serverside variable that I can read off and change when the callback comes? First time I deal with a bigger project like this and I am not really sure how to go about with this.

Some pseudo code or articles where I could read up on this matter would be great.

/Cheers

This is the route in question

```
server.express.post("/payment", async (req, res) => {
  // payment header
  const paymentHeader = {...}

  const body = {
    "payment": {
      ...
      "urls": {
        "hostUrls": ["https://example.com"],
        "paymentUrl": "http://example.com/perform-payment",
        "completeUrl": "https://example.com/payment-completed",
        "cancelUrl": "https://example.com/payment-canceled",
        "callbackUrl": "https://example.com/payment-callback",
        "logoUrl": "https://example.com/logo.png",
        "termsOfServiceUrl": "https://example.com/terms.pdf"
      },
      ...
    }
  }

  axios
    .post(
      `${process.env.PAYMENT_URL}/psp/swish/payments`,
      body,
      paymentHeader
    )
    .then(response => {
      console.log('2d post /payment')
      axios.post(`${process.env.PAYMENT_URL}${response.data.payment.id}/sales`, {
        "transaction": {
          "msisdn": "+46739000001"
        },
        paymentHeader

      }
      ).then(response => console.log(response.data)).catch(err => console.log(err.response.data))
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response.data));
});
```

Comment: For better help I encourage you to provide a basic code example of your approach.

Comment: What was the answer to this question? I am struggling with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly but I think this may help you:

```
axios.get('/your-backend-api')
        .then( (response) => {
            console.log("response", response.data);
            //Do what you want with response after server answered
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error);
            //server had a problem 
        });
```

Comment: so if I set up a /callback route I will get a response there with a axios.get call? Since there will be multiple payments at once possible I need to do a dynamic adress like /callback/:id then ?